# bash script exercise on OS X/Linux

Tags: linux, macos, bash

I have to do an exercise: there is a file which contains this text

dirA dirB

dirX dirY

dirA dirD

Each line has two directories, the script must check for each line if any file of the first directory is contained in the second directory. Here is the script:

```
if [ $# -ne 2 ];then
echo "Error! Insufficient parameters"
exit 1
fi
if [ ! -f $1 ];then
echo "$1 is not a file"
exit 2
fi
if [ -f $2 ];then
echo "$2 already exists"
exit 3
fi

file=$(cat $1)
file_output=$(touch $2)
count=0
dir_a=''
dir_b=''

for i in $file ; do
    if [ $count -eq 0 ];then
        dir_a=$i
        let count=$count+1
        continue
    fi
    if [ $count -eq 1 ];then
        dir_b=$i
        let count=0
        for f in $(ls $dir_a) ; do
            if [ -f $dir_b/$f ];then
                echo "found"
            fi
        done
    fi
done
```

The problem is that it doesn't check the last couple, in the case of the example above it won't check the couple "dirA dirD".
Any ideas for this strange behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

..... What?

```
while read src dest
do
  for file in "$src"/*
  do
    if [ -e "$dest"/"${file##*/}" ]
    then
      echo "Found: $src $dest"
      break
    fi
  done
done
```

Comment: thanks for this alternative solution, but I would like to understand what is wrong with my loop.